# Indexing a multi-dimensional numpy array with an index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having a hard time indexing a two-dimensional array given an indexing array.

Suppose I have:

```
# Indexing array 
idx = np.array([0,2,1,2,1])

# Array to be indexed
my_array = np.array([[0,2,1], [0,5,1], [1,2,1], [5,1,3], [2,6,2]])
```

And the expected output should be the `0` index of the first entry of `my_array`, the `2` index of the second entry of `my_array` and so on, thus:

```
# Expected output
expected_array = np.array([0,1,2,3,6])
```

I have actually made it using a for-loop:

```
# Using for-loop
expected_array = np.array([])
for i in range(len(my_array)):
    expected_array = np.append(idx, my_array[i][idx[i]])
```

But I am wondering if there is a way of possibly doing **array-indexing without the use of for-loops**?  Assume that `len(idx)==len(my_array)` all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.arange` to make an array to index rows, which will just be each row at a time. Then use your `idx` array to index out of each row.

```
>>> my_array[np.arange(my_array.shape[0]), idx]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6])
```